# Manually change colour of one factor level in ggplot2 stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm giving a presentation, and would like to highlight the rate of occurrence of one of my factor levels on a slide by retaining the colour of this particular factor level, whilst greying out the other factor levels across other variables.

[image]

Using the `Arthritis` data set in the `vcd` library as an example:

```
library(vcd)
ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = Sex, fill = Improved)) + geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

When, for example, I’m telling the audience about the marked improvement in the males, can I have a version of the plot which retains the colour of marked improvement in males, but greys out everything else? Preferably by using different shades of grey to keep the boundaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Arthritis)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sex, group = Improved), fill = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "grey50", "black"), position = "fill")
```

[image]

To change the specified field, while others keep the default ggplot colors:

```
ggplot(Arthritis)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sex,
               group = Improved),
           fill = c(rev(hue_pal()(3)),
                    "black",
                    hue_pal()(3)[2:1]),
            position = "fill")
```

[image]

or to grey out the rest with shades

```
ggplot(Arthritis)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sex,
               group = Improved),
           fill = c(paste0("grey", 7:9*10),
                    hue_pal()(3)[3],
                    paste0("grey", 8:9*10)),
           position = "fill")
```

[image]

to keep the legend just plot the above over your initial layer:

```
ggplot(Arthritis)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sex, fill = Improved),  position = "fill")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sex,
               group = Improved),
           fill = c(paste0("grey", 7:9*10),
                    hue_pal()(3)[3],
                    paste0("grey", 8:9*10)),
           position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! For anyone trying to replicate, `hue_pal` needs the `scales` package loaded.

Comment: @dmt Thank you for the suggestion. I have added required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Add

`scale_fill_manual(values=c("Marked" = "RoyalBlue", "Some" = "DarkGrey", "None"="LightGrey"))`

Full `ggplot` call:

```
ggplot(Arthritis, aes(x = Sex, fill = Improved)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Marked" = "RoyalBlue", "Some" = "DarkGrey", "None"="LightGrey"))
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but what I want is to highlight just the males.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to replace the data points we'd like to highlight by NAs and then use `scale_fill_grey` to colour them with the argument `na.value`. We relabel the legend manually to show the original nomenclature.

**Highlight all Marked**

```
library(dplyr)    
ggplot(Arthritis %>% 
             mutate(Improved = replace(Improved, Improved == "Marked", NA))) + 
      geom_bar(position = "fill", aes(x = Sex, fill = Improved))+
      scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.6, na.value = "RoyalBlue", 
                      labels = c("None", "Some", "Marked"))
```

[image]

**Highlight Male Marked**

```
ggplot(Arthritis %>% 
         mutate(Improved = replace(Improved, Improved== "Marked" & Sex == "Male", NA))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", aes(x = Sex, fill = Improved))+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2, na.value = "RoyalBlue",
                  labels = c("None", "Some", "Marked", "Marked"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column which contains the map of colors and use it with `scales_fill_identity()`.

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2017-11-18

library(vcd)
#> Loading required package: grid

lvls <- levels(Arthritis$Improved)
color_maps <- scales::grey_pal(start = 0.8, end = 0.9)(length(lvls))
names(color_maps) <- lvls


library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

Arthritis_w_fill <- Arthritis %>%
  mutate(
    fill = if_else(
      Sex == "Male" & Improved == "Marked",
      "blue",
      color_maps[Improved]
  )
)


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Arthritis_w_fill, aes(x = Sex, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend",
                      breaks = c(color_maps, "blue"),
                      labels = c(lvls, 'Sex == "Male" & Improved == "Marked"'))
```

[image]